# What does a number do after the "%" symbol?

Tags: c, string, format

`#define TITLES "* %10s * %10s %10s %11s *\n"`

is a bit of pre-code that I have in a buggy C program, and I have no idea what the numbers after the percent symbol do.

I know that the percent symbol [is the string format specifier symbol in C](https://codeforwin.org/2015/05/list-of-all-format-specifiers-in-c-programming.html). However, I've only seen the percent symbol followed directly by a letter, rather than a number (s for string, l for long, and so on).

I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>ed through all of [this document](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html) and was unable to find a single instance of the percent symbol followed by any digit 0-9

What do the numbers do in the given code bit? Are they even supposed to be there?

Comment: You are just creating a string constant holding a pre-defined *format string* to use with the `printf` (or similar) function. That way if you need to print output formatted as `TITLES` in a number of places, it is simply `printf (TITLES, s1, s2, s3, s4);` which is a lot shorter than `printf ("* %10s * %10s %10s %11s *\n", s1, s2, s3, s4);` (the four strings `s1, s2, s3, s4` are just for example, your variable names would be different. You can `#define` character, string, integer or floating-point constants in this manner.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks; I could tell that that what the piece as a whole was doing (er, supposed to do) based on the context; I was just befuddled by the numbers.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, I don't think the OP were asking how to use `printf` but the question was specifically about the digits  after the `%` !

Comment: So....is this question getting downvotes because it's so basic? Is there any way I could improve the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Minimum number of characters to be printed. If the value to be printed is shorter than this number, the result is padded with blank spaces. The value is not truncated even if the result is larger.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    printf(">%10s<", "foo");
}
```

gives `>       foo<`

Comment: Thanks! Does it matter at all that the link comes from a c++ site? I know the two are very similar.

Comment: Doesn't matter. That is a C function that is also available in C++.

Answer (score 2):

> The numbers are An optional digit string specifying a field width.

Check the [Man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf).

Suppose you have `printf("<%6s>", "ABC");` which gives an output:

```
<   ABC>
```

where the string is shifted to the left by (`3 = 6 - 3`) characters. if the length of the string (or number) is equal or higher than the field width then the output would be the same as if it was absent.

In case of a negative field width `printf("<%-6s>", "ABC");`, the result will be shifted to the right like this

```
<ABC   >
```